# Red5 and unique naming of FLV files

Tags: php, red5, rtmp

I've implemented Red5 on a server and, through a webpage, integrated the Red5Recorder which results in a user being able to record a file to the server through their webcam.

What I can't quite figure out, however, is how to uniquely name the resulting file on the server.

The Red5Recorder has a parameter "fileName" which can be modified by feeding it a new value through JavaScript, but that relies on client-side security (aka: nonexistent).  If exploited (which wouldn't be hard), it could allow a user to record videos as another user.

Given that all users who record video will be logged in (have an active $_SESSION[] variable), if there was a way to create a file name based on this input, that would be perfect.

Does anyone here have any experience with this?  Ideas?  Workarounds?  I'm not familiar with RTMP or how to manage it (that I got this far is, on its own, substantially impressive to me).

Thanks for any help, suggestions, or directions you can provide!

EDIT --

The question still stands, but I'm working on a work-around for this at the moment.  The concept would be that the webpage is loaded with a random token generated by PHP inserted into the JavaScript to set the 'fileName' attribute.  This token is also inserted into the DB, and attributed to the user's account.  When a .flv hits the streams directory, it's matched with a token in the DB and associated with that user, at which point the token is destroyed (assuring that it's a 'use once' token).

It's pretty much the same concept behind confirming email accounts - only instead of confirming accounts we're confirming videos.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid) with [`session_name()`](http://php.net/session_name).

Comment: Does Red5 tie in with PHP like that?  I don't know how to link the two, mostly because I have no idea how exactly Red5 works on the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly going to sound complicated, i'm sure but this is totally possible via Red5. You could pass a querystring via the RTMP url and intercept it on the server side to construct a custom filename. This will require modification of the Red5 app that you're using. Connecting with this:

```
rtmp://yourserver/yourapp/room?streamName=mystream
```

Could be accessed in the application connect like so:

```
  public boolean appConnect(IConnection conn, Object[] params) {
    Map connParams = conn.getConnectParams();
    if (connParams != null) {
      String streamName = connParams.get("queryString") != null ? connParams.get("queryString").get("streamName") : null;
    }
  }
```